# Deploying Solution with C++ Baclground-Task to physical WP8.1 Device

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone

I downloaded [an example-project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df) using a background task implemented in C++. I can compile the example and deploy it on the WP8.1 emulator only.

Deploying to a phyical WP8.1 device fails `(Error DEP3311 x86-package cannot be deployed to windows phone device)`.

Is there a way to test it on physical devices? How do I have to configure the project?

Comment: @mvermef What do I have to recompile as ARM? Only the background task? That leads to another error message (process architectures (x86 & arm) do not match). I tried several build-configurations, all resulting in an error.

Comment: to place on the device both if they are in C++ have to be ARM.  remember DEVICE is ARM based not X86. only the emulator is x86.  SQLite projects have to ARM as well so the SQLite dll is ARM compiled.

Comment: Only the background task is implemented in C++, the main program is a C#-project. I can't set the platform to ARM there (only Any CPU and x86).

Comment: you should be able to set the C# project to ARM as well...  That is the only way it will work.  You might have to create a new profile for C# that is ARM.  VS 2013 has it I assume that is the version you are using.

Comment: I finally managed to deploy it to the phone! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Click the down arrow next to your Debug configuration. Choose Configuration Manager and change the x86 to ARM.

It helped me since the settings on the project-properties pages seemed to fail working.